# What is the Hibernate Equivalent of this query?(Adding Two Columns)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm

This is the query

```
SELECT id, name, sub1, sub2, sub1 + sub2 AS total 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY sub1 + sub2 ASC
```

What I am trying to do here is that I will add sub1 and sub2 and the result would be named TOTAL, and I will use TOTAL for Order By. so far this is how I've come up with but it is not rendering proper reults

```
sess().createSQLQuery("SELECT *, SUB1+ SUB2 AS TOTAL FROM TRACKS order by TOTAL ").addEntity(Student.class).list();
```

What is the hibernate or Query Criteria equivalent of what I am trying to do?

Comment: Assuming mytable is the class name of an entity, this is valid HQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such operation in JPQL, But what you could do is do a native query as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM TRACKS order by SUB1+ SUB2"
```

And make a getter like:

```
public Double getTotal(){ //Replace Double for the data type you use
    return sub1 + sub2;
}
```

That way you could order the query as you want.

Is this what you're trying to do? I'm not sure if I understood quite well your question

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you have two options: Mapping or custom OrderBy object.

1) Mapping: If the `Total` would be used often, you can extend your entity mapping and create *calculated/readonly* property (seee [5.1.11. Property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property)):

```
<property name="total" formula="(sub1 + sub2)" insert="false" udpate="false" />
```

Now, we can use this value for Order by easily (and anywhere):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
...
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("total"));
```

2) We are still in the OOP world. The `criteria.addOrder()` operation, expects the `Order` object instance. So we can pass the Custom one: 'MyOrder'. In our case, it could be object accepting any *valid* SQL statement and directly inject that into ORDER BY:

```
public class MyOrder extends Order {
    public MyOrder(String propertyName, boolean ascending) {
        super(propertyName, ascending);
    }

    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        StringBuilder fragment = new StringBuilder();
        fragment.append(propertyName );
        fragment.append( ascending ? " asc" : " desc" );
        return fragment.toString();
    }
}
```

Now, we can inject any (valid) SQL Script into ORDER BY this way:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class);
...
criteria.addOrder(new MyOrder("(sub1 + sub2)", true));
```